# convex polygon and $P$ a point inside it

Tags: geometry

Let $C$ be a convex polygon and $P$ a point inside it. Let $N$ be number of
vertices, such that an interval connecting $P$ to the vertex divides the
angle of $C$ into two acute angles. Denote $ n $ number of sides of $C$, such
that the foot of perpendicular from $P$ to that side is strictly inside
that side.
Proof that $N=n$.

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked several questions in a quick succession. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, stackexchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi/4770#4770).

Comment: didn't know that! thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

Let p be the number of sides.  Notice that the condition of the foot perpendicular to a side $(v_0,v_1)$ being strictly within the side is equivalent to the condition that the angles $P,v0,v1$ and $P,v1,v0$ are both acute, and when the condition fails, exactly one of the two angles is non-acute (i.e. obtuse or right).  Consider the $2p$ angles consisting of all $P,v_0,v_1$ and $P,v_1,v_0$  where $v_0,v_1$ are adjacent vertices; notice that, among those, there's exactly one non-acute angle whenever a vertex did *not* contribute to N, and also there's exactly one non-acute angle whenever a side did *not* contribute to n.  Therefore p-N = (number of non-acute angles out of these $2p$) = p-n, so N = n.